# find related tables based on column value using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL. 
I know one table column value. Based on the column name/value, i should know all the related tables  .For example: i know the column name- 'name' and column value - 'Ravi' and the table name ' employee'. Now i want to know all the tables related to the 'employee' table which is referred column name ' name' and value 'ravi' .

Comment: The related tables are based on the data model and are "exposed" by SQL.

Comment: That's a mighty tall order for a newbie.  To get the tables, you will have to query the system tables.  Then you would have to query them to find matching records.

Comment: The concept is incorrect, too. The table `employee` should have a primary key, something like an `employee_id`; any other tables (like job history, annual evaluations etc.) should relate to `employees` based on this primary key, not on the name; they will not have the name anywhere.

Comment: As others have noted, something is fishy here. Either you are misunderstanding your schema, or your schema is very poorly made and should be fixed. Nearly any time you find yourself trying to dynamically determine which DB object (table, view, field) based on a record's value, you are heading down the wrong path.